# Underline inside eqnarray

Tags: equations

I have now the version

[image: now]

and want to change it to something like

[image: I want it like this]

The equations are in `eqnarray` and I want to underline only the last line. Is this possible?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! `eqnarray` is outdated. Please use `align` or something similar. And please provide a working document, not just a screenshot of what you want to have

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi Mike. To help us help you, add a Minimum Working Example to your question. This should be a piece of code containing your problem that starts with \documentclass and end with \end{document} so that other users can compile it and see how to help you out.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry, it was my plan to don't show my sources. I am newbie in LaTeX and I know my work is not perfect. I prefer someone with experiences show me some working example rather then fix my "spaghetti source". Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to underline the parts to the left and the right of the `&` separately.  The `\mathstrut`s are used to vertically align the two halves and add extra space before the `=` and below the denominator.  For large structures one can use `\vphantom` to equalize the depths.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\frac{12(x+7y)}{4} - \frac{12(3x+8y)}{3} &= 1 \cdot 12\\
\underline{\frac{21(3x+4y)}{\mathstrut 3} - \frac{21(4x+5y)}{7}} &
\underline{\vphantom{\frac{21(3x+4y)}{\mathstrut 3} - \frac{21(4x+5y)}{7}}=4 \cdot 21}\\
-9x - 11y &= 12\\
\underline{\mathstrut 9x + 43y} &\underline{\mathstrut= 84}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Comment: Hello, thank you, it looks great in some cases, but when I use \dfrac on one side of equation, \mathstrut is not working and underline is shifted. Or I dont know how to use \mathstrut correctly... I tried 
\underline{\mathstrut \dfrac{9x + 43y}{1}} &\underline{\mathstrut = 84}

Comment: I added an example using \vphantom.  You can also use \savebox, \usebox and \rule.

Comment: Thank you very much, marked as solved, it is exactly what I need.